# ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut in Android

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

```
DALVIK THREADS:
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2aae0900 self=0xcec8
  | sysTid=4608 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1876209304
  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:662)
  at org.android.PeruLink.android_PeruLink.createSoundEffectPlayerAndPlaySound(android_PeruLink.java:368)
  at org.android.PeruLink.android_PeruLink.onClick(android_PeruLink.java:745)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2414)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8838)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4680)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #3" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2fed0158 self=0x13eed8
  | sysTid=4620 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3163808
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"DispatcherThread" prio=5 tid=10 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2fe975a8 self=0x2f3848
  | sysTid=4618 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3094920
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x2fe9bf38> (a android.os.MessageQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:288)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:146)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:110)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"Thread-10" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2fe858b8 self=0x2ad978
  | sysTid=4617 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2741680
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"CookieSyncManager" prio=5 tid=8 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2fe86888 self=0x145e90
  | sysTid=4616 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=2597608
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x2fe74bc0> (a android.os.MessageQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:326)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:142)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:110)
  at android.webkit.WebSyncManager.run(WebSyncManager.java:90)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

"WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2fe817f8 self=0x262ff8
  | sysTid=4614 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2502968
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x2fe81ae0> (a android.os.MessageQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:288)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:146)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:110)
  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:665)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=6 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2fe553c0 self=0x134580
  | sysTid=4613 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1267984
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=5 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2fe55300 self=0x12d7b8
  | sysTid=4612 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1241448
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2fe4e2a0 self=0x134a10
  | sysTid=4611 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1299968
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2fe4e1e8 self=0x133c60
  | sysTid=4610 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1287176
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2e704b58 self=0x12f010
  | sysTid=4609 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1275152
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

There is not much details that I can give since I have not dealt with this issues before, it is a freeze and i would like to know how to handle and fix this issue. It says that the cause is ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut